# Error while executing command: dotnet restore Project/Project.csproj. Reason: exit status 1

Tags: .net, git, aws-codecommit

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Restore started on `date`
      - pip install --upgrade awscli
      - dotnet restore Project/Project.csproj
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - dotnet publish -c release -o ./build_output Project/Project.csproj
      - dotnet vstest Project/bin/Project.dll
artifacts:
  files:
    - Project/obj/**/*
    - scripts/**/*
    - appspec.yml
```

When i commit my code and push code through codeStar that time face the issue in codeBuild.

Answer (score 0):

It's and old question and I'm quite a newbie with AWS, but in case this helps anybody out there.

The same thing happened to me when the paths I was using included the repository name. You should go to your repository and check if those paths are correct from its root.